# Locating the position of a word from a list

Tags: python

Hi I'm doing an assignment for school and part of it involves displaying the position of a word in a sentence and I searched it up and found this:

```
for i in [i for i,x in enumerate(list, start=1) if x == word]:
     print (i)
```

However I don't understand *how* this works so could someone please break it up and explain it to me

If it helps this is the rest of my code for this part of the assignment:

```
list = ["apple", "banana", "carrot","pear"]
print (list)
word = input("Enter a word from this list: ")
for i in [i for i,x in enumerate(list, start=1) if x == word]:
      print (i)
```

Comment: http://pythontutor.com visualizes the code and is an excellent tool to see how the code works. Aside from that `enumerate` unpacks the list you sent through and returns `i` which is the index and `x` which is the word. If your `x` matches your word, then `i`, which is the index is returned.

Answer (score 1):

### Awkwardness

First, you should not use `list` as a variable because [`list`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html) is one of the default Python functions. If you do so, the `list()` function (which is also a type) is replace by your variable in the local scope. So I renamed it `alist`.

```
alist = ["apple", "banana", "carrot", "pear"]
```

### Explanation

The following statement is a comprehension list:

```
result = [i for i, x in enumerate(alist, start=1) if x == word]
```

This comprehension list can be written like this:

```
result = []
for i, x in enumerate(alist, start=1):
    if x == word:
        result.append(i)
```

For instance:

```
>>> alist = ["apple", "banana", "carrot", "pear"]
>>> word = "carrot"
>>> [i for i, x in enumerate(alist, start=1) if x == word]
[3]
```

This comprehension list returns all the positions of the word "carrot" in ["apple", "banana", "carrot", "pear"].

The loop:

```
for i in [i for i, x in enumerate(alist, start=1) if x == word]:
    print(i)
```

Is vainly complex because it iterates the comprehension list.

You can simplify like this:

```
print([i for i, x in enumerate(alist, start=1) if x == word])
```

Or:

```
for i, x in enumerate(alist, start=1):
    if x == word:
        print(i)
```

*Note: `alist.index(word) + 1` can give the first word position in the list.*